# End of record reached while expected to parse column '"TRANSIENT_STAGE_TABLE in SNOWFLAKE DATAWAREHOUSE

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have a file in .csv format in S3, When i am trying to load to Snowflake , i am getting error as " End of record reached while expected to parse column '"TRANSIENT_STAGE_TABLE".

My File looks like

```
Account_Activity_Type , Batch_ID , reference, Merchant
UNRECONCILED PAYMENT, cycleRef, @#$2&,
```

Sample Data which is throwing Error

Data

```
Account_Activity_Type,Batch_ID,Batch_Sent_Date,Bank_Batch_ID,Bank_Account_Updated,Amount_Currency,Batch_Credit_Debit_Mark,Amount,Statement_Ref,Bank_Statement_Ref,Merchant_Bank_Account_Updated,Merchant_Party_ID,Merchant_Contract_ID,External_Original_Transaction_ID,External_Original_Transaction_Date
UNRECONCILED DISBURSEMENT,cycleRef,,batchId1,,USD,CREDIT,100,@#$2&,id,,,,,
UNRECONCILED DISBURSEMENT_RETURN,cycleRef,,batchId1,,USD,CREDIT,1000,${originationId},id,,,,,
UNRECONCILED DISBURSEMENT_RETURN,cycleRef,,batchId1,,USD,CREDIT,100,@#$2&,id,,,,,
UNRECONCILED DISBURSEMENT_RETURN,cycleRef,,batchId1,,USD,CREDIT,100,${originationId},id,,,,,
```

Code i am using to load to SnowFlake Datawarehouse.

```
Create or replace FILE FORMAT SETTLEMENT_DQ

COMPRESSION = 'AUTO'
FIELD_DELIMITER = ','
RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n'
SKIP_HEADER = 1
--FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042'
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = NONE
TRIM_SPACE = FALSE
validate_UTF8=false
ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = FALSE
ESCAPE = 'NONE'
--ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\134'
ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE
DATE_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yyyy'
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO'
NULL_IF = ('NULL', 'null', '\N')
COMMENT = 'parse comma-delimited, double-quoted data'


insert into SETTLEMENT_DAILY 
(
Account_Activity_Type,
Batch_ID,
Batch_Sent_Date,
Bank_Batch_ID,
Bank_Account_Updated,
Amount_Currency,
Batch_Credit_Debit_Mark,
Amount,
Statement_Ref,
Bank_Statement_Ref,
Merchant_Bank_Account_Updated,
Merchant_Party_ID,
Merchant_Contract_ID,
External_Original_Transaction_ID,
External_Original_Transaction_Date
  )
SELECT 
T.$1,
T.$2,
T.$3,
T.$4,
T.$5,
T.$6,
T.$7,
T.$8,
T.$9,
T.$10,
T.$11,
T.$12,
T.$13,
T.$14,
T.$15
FROM @DEV_S3_DATA/SETTLEMENT/yearly_XN540000_UK.csv (FILE_FORMAT => 'SETTLEMENT_DQ') as T;
```

May someone please share your suggestion if it is known error.

Error:
End of record reached while expected to parse column '"TRANSIENT_STAGE_TABLE"["$15":15]' File 'SETTLEMENT/yearly_XN540000_UK.csv', line 5, 
character 92 Row 4, column "TRANSIENT_STAGE_TABLE"["$15":15]

Comment: Can you please post an example set of data that triggers this error ? A full reproducible case makes investigation dramatically easier

Comment: @MarcinZukowski: Hi Marcin, i had posted an example set of Data. Please help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MarcinZukowski: Hi Marcin, Please help me. I have never came across such scenario in Snowflake.

Comment: My source file have all special character like (~,`,@,&,^,-) in one of the column. may someone please help me if came across such scenario.

Comment: Hi @akhrot, we tried with your data/queries, and everything seems to work. Can you please double-check the data/queries you provided reproduce an issue ? Can you please post the exact statements you're using to create the table, and to put the file in the stage? For example, when the data is uploaded to the stage, did you disable compression?

Comment: @MarcinZukowski: Thanks a lot Marcin,
i have paste the full code from File format to data insertion from s3 to Snowflake table.
may i have the code which you are using to insert the data to table if you have.
Please share your suggestion

Comment: We just tried regular loading, but it didn't manifest the problem. I suggest you contact Snowflake support, and perhaps send them the exact file that is causing the problem. Maybe there's something weird there, like hidden characters, weird end of lines or something.